# Как проверить клик мыши над элементом?

Tags: javascript

Условие простое, есть кнопка

```
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

нужно отследить нажатие ее мышью для такого условия:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

if (hash == '' && btn.onclick()) {
  return;
}
```

Как правильно написать такое условие(проверку)?
Возможно в этой истории более правильно использования события - mousedown.

P.S. Данное условие должно проверить пустой ли хеш в URL + не нажата ли кнопка с классом btn.

Answer (score 1):

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

let checker = false;

btn.onclick = () => checker = true;

if (hash == '' && checker === true) {
  console.log('Button clicked');
} 
else console.log('Button not clicked');
```

Смысл в том, чтобы создать переменную в которой будет находиться состояние кликнул\не кликнул. Если кликнул, то `true`, если нет, то `false`. И дальше в зависимости от условий работать с этим.

Comment: Идея классная, только при клике не переключается в true

Comment: Переключается. Но только чтобы checker стал true всё-таки нужен клик, который произойдёт до выполнения if. В такой реализации, в if checker будет false. Можно как вариант присвоение чеккеру тру, перенести в ивентлистенер, по событию клик, и устанавливать его после нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

> Данное условие должно проверить пустой ли хеш в URL + не нажата ли кнопка с классом btn.

Могу предложить такой вариант проверки...

```js
const hash = ''
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (hash == '' && e.target.closest('.btn')) {
    console.log('Наш случай')
    return;
  }
})
```

```html
<button class='btn1'>btn 1</button>
<button class='btn'>btn</button>
<button class='btn2'>btn 2</button>
```